# Internal error: Oops: 17 on OMAP device

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, crash-dumps

I have the ARM OMAP system which is generatin Oops during some tests.
The system is still alive, but the  thread which has created the Oops has died.
I have pasted oops logs below. Please help me to debug this issue.

From log i see that:

```
Process appl (pid: 427, stack limit = 0x86faa2e8)
```

This proc 427 is one of 5 threads created within main process. I have the /proc/kallsyms file, and checked that the PC is showing the correct function (put_page+0x14) of crash.

### LOGS:

```
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.796 2013] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.796 2013] pgd = 86f94000
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.796 2013] [00000000] *pgd=87a9f031, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.796 2013] Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1] PREEMPT
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.796 2013] last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/spi/spi/dev
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.796 2013] Modules linked in: spi_mod hr_driver isp(P) spv(P) gp
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.796 2013] CPU: 0    Tainted: P            (2.6.33_Visor #1)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.796 2013] PC is at put_page+0x14/0x184
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.796 2013] LR is at __pskb_pull_tail+0x210/0x2b4
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.796 2013] pc : [<800b22c4>]    lr : [<80230254>]    psr: 60000013
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] sp : 86fabb28  ip : 800b22c4  fp : 86fabb44
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] r10: 00000054  r9 : 00000006  r8 : 00000007
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] r7 : 00000007  r6 : 00000000  r5 : 00000000  r4 : 87340500
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] r3 : 86fe1cc0  r2 : 86fe1d44  r1 : 86fe1d14  r0 : 00000000
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 86f94019  DAC: 00000015
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] Process appl (pid: 427, stack limit = 0x86faa2e8)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] Stack: (0x86fabb28 to 0x86fac000)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] bb20:                   86fe1cc0 87340500 00000000 00000000 86fabb6c 86fabb48
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] bb40: 80230254 800b22bc 87340500 86d49140 87a2a800 00000000 86d49154 00000000
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] bb60: 86fabb9c 86fabb70 802392a0 80230050 87340500 0000000e 00000000 87340500
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] bb80: 86d49140 0000000e 00000000 86d49154 86fabbc4 86fabba0 8025a6a0 802391f4
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] bba0: 87340500 86faa000 87a2a800 00000000 86fe1c8c 0000ffff 86fabbe4 86fabbc8
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] bbc0: 8025a770 8025a434 8025a6d8 87340500 86fe1c78 87340500 86fabbfc 86fabbe8
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] bbe0: 802583d8 8025a6e4 00000000 86d7fa80 86fabc94 86fabc00 80259fec 802583b0
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] bc00: 802555a4 802555e4 00000001 86fabc38 00000102 00000000 802c69bc 80237f9c
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] bc20: 87a2ab88 86fabc38 86fabc54 86fabc38 8002d4dc 8002bf80 8002bfa4 00000001
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.812 2013] bc40: 8026c77c 86faa000 86fabc7c 86fabc58 8002bfe0 8002d4c4 86fabcec 00000001
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bc60: 8026c77c 87ab3080 00000014 86d7fa80 87340500 86faa000 00000014 86fe1c8c
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bc80: 00000006 0000ffff 86fabcec 86fabc98 8026c7a0 80259d04 86fabcec 00000020
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bca0: 000000c0 87340500 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bcc0: 87340500 86d7fa80 87340500 86d7fae4 000000fa 86faa000 00000006 86d7fd0c
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bce0: 86fabd04 86fabcf0 8026c960 8026c02c 86d7fa80 00000000 86fabd24 86fabd08
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bd00: 8026104c 8026c898 8022f70c 800d3964 86d7fa80 00000006 86fabd9c 86fabd28
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bd20: 802617bc 80260f04 8002d4dc 8002bf80 8002bfa4 00000001 00000000 86d7fae4
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bd40: 86d7fde8 86d7fb18 86d7fd28 00000000 86fabf3c 00000001 00000000 00000000
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bd60: 00000001 00000000 86fabd8c 86fabd78 80049998 86fabf3c 803c0e8c 00000040
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bd80: 00000000 00000040 86faa000 2e4128a2 86fabdd4 86fabda0 80229d34 80261068
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bda0: 00000040 00000000 86fabdb4 00000000 00000500 00000000 00000000 86fabde0
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bdc0: 00000100 86fabf3c 86fabeb4 86fabdd8 8022767c 80229cf4 00000040 86fabde8
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] bde0: 802277c4 80261de0 00000000 00000001 ffffffff 00000000 00000000 00000000
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] be00: 00000000 00000000 87a70740 86fabe18 00000000 00000000 8002bfa4 00000001
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] be20: 86fabe58 86fabf60 86fabe5c 86fabe38 8002bfe0 8002d4c4 86fabe94 00000001
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] be40: 800d9094 86fabf60 00000000 00000040 86fabe74 86fabe60 80049998 8009ec3c
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.828 2013] be60: 00000040 00000100 87541080 86fabe78 00000000 86fabf3c 86fabe78 fffffff7
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.843 2013] be80: 80226524 802278a8 86fabeb4 86fabe98 802278a8 8022651c 00000040 87541080
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.843 2013] bea0: 00000100 006766f0 86fabf8c 86fabeb8 8022804c 802275d8 8002bfa4 87803140
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.843 2013] bec0: 86f67800 a0000013 87800440 00000003 86fabefc 86fabee0 800d3944 8009ed38
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.843 2013] bee0: 00000000 00000508 87a25290 86faa000 86fabf14 86fabf00 80186658 800d3810
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.843 2013] bf00: 86f67800 00000508 86fabf7c 86fabf18 80186d90 80186648 86fabf3c 2e4128a0
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.843 2013] bf20: 86fabf8c 87a25290 87a25298 803b0d7c 86fabf84 00100100 00200200 86fabebc
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.843 2013] bf40: 00000080 86fabf58 00000001 00000000 00000000 2e41289c 006766f6 000000fa
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.843 2013] bf60: 00000001 fffffff7 86faa000 006766ec 0066b138 00000000 00000123 8002a328
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.843 2013] bf80: 86fabfa4 86fabf90 802280cc 80227fc4 00000000 00000000 00000000 86fabfa8
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.843 2013] bfa0: 8002a100 802280b0 006766ec 0066b138 0000000f 006766f0 00000100 00000040
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.843 2013] bfc0: 006766ec 0066b138 00000000 00000123 00000740 0066b138 2e4128a2 000005d8
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.843 2013] bfe0: 00000000 2e411a30 2ad8cfe4 2ad7fc24 80000010 0000000f 00000000 00000000
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.968 2013] Backtrace: 
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.968 2013] [<800b22b0>] (put_page+0x0/0x184) from [<80230254>] (__pskb_pull_tail+0x210/0x2b4)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.968 2013]  r6:00000000 r5:00000000 r4:87340500 r3:86fe1cc0
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<80230044>] (__pskb_pull_tail+0x0/0x2b4) from [<802392a0>] (dev_queue_xmit+0xb8/0x474)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<802391e8>] (dev_queue_xmit+0x0/0x474) from [<8025a6a0>] (ip_finish_output+0x278/0x2b0)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013]  r8:86d49154 r7:00000000 r6:0000000e r5:86d49140 r4:87340500
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<8025a428>] (ip_finish_output+0x0/0x2b0) from [<8025a770>] (ip_output+0x98/0xa0)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<8025a6d8>] (ip_output+0x0/0xa0) from [<802583d8>] (ip_local_out+0x34/0x38)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013]  r6:87340500 r5:86fe1c78 r4:87340500 r3:8025a6d8
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<802583a4>] (ip_local_out+0x0/0x38) from [<80259fec>] (ip_queue_xmit+0x2f4/0x364)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013]  r4:86d7fa80 r3:00000000
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<80259cf8>] (ip_queue_xmit+0x0/0x364) from [<8026c7a0>] (tcp_transmit_skb+0x780/0x7dc)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<8026c020>] (tcp_transmit_skb+0x0/0x7dc) from [<8026c960>] (tcp_send_ack+0xd4/0xdc)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<8026c88c>] (tcp_send_ack+0x0/0xdc) from [<8026104c>] (tcp_cleanup_rbuf+0x154/0x164)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013]  r5:00000000 r4:86d7fa80
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<80260ef8>] (tcp_cleanup_rbuf+0x0/0x164) from [<802617bc>] (tcp_recvmsg+0x760/0x87c)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013]  r5:00000006 r4:86d7fa80
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<8026105c>] (tcp_recvmsg+0x0/0x87c) from [<80229d34>] (sock_common_recvmsg+0x4c/0x60)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<80229ce8>] (sock_common_recvmsg+0x0/0x60) from [<8022767c>] (sock_recvmsg+0xb0/0xcc)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013]  r6:86fabf3c r5:00000100 r4:86fabde0
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<802275cc>] (sock_recvmsg+0x0/0xcc) from [<8022804c>] (sys_recvfrom+0x94/0xec)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013]  r6:006766f0 r5:00000100 r4:87541080
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<80227fb8>] (sys_recvfrom+0x0/0xec) from [<802280cc>] (sys_recv+0x28/0x30)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013]  r8:8002a328 r7:00000123 r6:00000000 r5:0066b138 r4:006766ec
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] [<802280a4>] (sys_recv+0x0/0x30) from [<8002a100>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x38)
[Wed Mar 27 19:34:51.984 2013] Code: e92dd878 e24cb004 e52de004 ebfddfbf (e5903000)
```

Comment: I don't want to mislead you. On the second though, the crash trace should not happen, your NIC driver and TCP/IP stack are both fine. A possiblity is that your test might overwrite some kernel memory. You may check what test you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Guess some bug in TCP/IP stack, conflict with S/G IO features in your network interface card (NIC) driver.

you can check if your NIC driver has these feature flags NETIF_F_FRAGLIST and NETIF_F_SG set, if yes, try unset them, see if this problem still happens.

Comment: Thanks for reply, how to check if these flags are enabled or not ? from source ? Output of ifconfig doesn't show these flags...

 $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:10.99.11.54  Bcast:10.99.15.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9874632 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9487764 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:631832793 (602.5 MiB)  TX bytes:1997700511 (1.8 GiB)
          Interrupt:181